# Call Javascript from recurring loop with incremental IDs

Tags: javascript, php

I have this php site and i use javascript with it.
One of the pages is an entry form with 10 lines to enter data in.
One line in this case would be coded in this way:

```
echo "<td style='border-width: 0'><input type='text' id = 'price1' style = 'font-size: 10px' name='poline1[price]' size='7'></td>";
```

Right next to this input field there is a button:

```
echo "<td style='border-width: 0'><a href = 'javascript:void(0)' onClick = 'copyRow1;' class='button6'>Copy Down</a></td>";
```

Javascript function copyRow1 is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function copyRow1() {
        document.fabricorder.price2.value = document.fabricorder.price1.value;
    }
</script>
```

It copies inputted value from input box ID = price1 into input box ID = price2.

I have 10 Javascript functions like this
copyRow1(), copyRow2(), copyRow3(), etc....

It works fine but I am trying to optimize all the code to make it easier for modifications and now I want to loop all my lines.

So I want change my line script in this way:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; ++$i){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td style='border-width: 0'><input type='text' id = 'price$i' style = 'font-size: 10px' name='poline[$i][price]' size='7'></td>";
echo "<td style='border-width: 0'><a href = 'javascript:void(0)' onClick = 'copyRow($i);' class='button6'>Copy Down</a></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
```

and my function this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function copyRow(i) {
        document.fabricorder.price(i+1).value = document.fabricorder.price(i).value;
    }
</script>
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Please define "this doesn't work".

Comment: In the expression `document.fabricorder.price(i+1).value`, `document.fabricorder.price` will be treated as a function and be called (which "doesn't work").

Comment: Teemu, basically this doesn't copy any data from line 1 into line 2.

Comment: Felix, so how do i approach this then?

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your `copyRow` function to:

```
 function copyRow(i) {
      for (var j=i,numRows=document.fabricorder.length;j<numRows;j++) {
           document.fabricorder["price"+(j+1)].value = document.fabricorder["price"+(j+1)].value;
      }
 }
```

You need to loop over all input fields, copying each value to the next.  It's hard to give you 100% working code without seeing 100% of your code.  Can you put it in a JSFiddle?

Comment: Please tell the OP why they should "try".

Comment: Even without trying I have a hunch that `document.fabricorder.price(j+1)` will throw an error.

Comment: If you have jQuery a better way might be to loop and select each input like so: `$("#price"+i).val()`

Comment: Scott, i don't need to copy from 1st row into all other rows. I have 10 rows and 9 buttons. Button 1 copies from row1 into row2, button 2 copies from Row2 into Row3 and so on.
I tried to format the code the way you suggested:
    function copyRow(i) {
    document.fabricorder.["price"+(i+1)].value = document.fabricorder.["price"+i].value;
    } but it still doesn't copy the data.

Comment: With jQuery, you should be able to copy a single row via:

    $("#price"+i).val($("#price"+j).val())

Where `i` is the number of the first row and `j` is the second row.